# Why does definite integral has a subtraction operation?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> In the Fundamental Theorem for Definite Integrals, the region is an interval
>   [a; b] on the input axis so the edge of the region consists of two points a and
>   b on the axis. The function is a function of one variable and the derivative is
>   the first kind of derivative you learned about. In words, the theorem says that
>   integrating the derivative F0 over the interval [a; b] is the same as adding up the function F for the two endpoints. But wait, isn't F(b) - F(a) a difference rather than a sum? Yes, but we can think of it as (-1)F(a)+F(b). The factor
>   of -1 relates to the issue of *orientation*.

**Here, what is the meaning of *orientation*?**

**I don't understand the reason where the (-1) comes from...**

Answer (score 2):

The orientation belongs to an interpretation as trivial case of the (general, with differential forms) theorem of Stokes. In short, the real line has an orientation pointing towards $+\infty$, and the interval ends have outward pointing "normals". For $b$ this normal has the same orientation as the real line, for $a$ the orientations are opposite, the factor $-1$ represents that reversal.

Comment: Solid answer! +1